# Как получить строку по индексу?

Tags: java

Имеется строковый массив:

```
String[] animals  = {"cat", "dog"};
```

Метод `Arrays.toString(animals)` вернет следующее:
 `[cat, dog]`.Обратиться подобным методом, но с указанием индекса
 `Arrays.toString(animals[0])`уже не работает.

Как получить в строковом виде слово cat из массива animals без всяких скобок массива?

Comment: Без скобок массива? Хех) `String cat = Arrays.asList(animals).get(0);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Метод `Arrays.toString(...)` возвращает строковое представление **массива**, с другими типа данных этот метод не работает.

Получить элемент массива по индексу можно с помощью стандартной конструкции:

```
String animal = animals[0];
```

Comment: пипец как просто оказывается

Answer (score 1):

String[] animals в данном случае - массив строк (может не правильно я это называю, но суть та же)

соответственно, для получения конкретного значения по индексу (ключу) нужно по индексу(ключу) и обращаться:

```
String value = animals[key];
```

явный пример:

```
String[] animals  = {"cat", "dog"};
int index = 0;
String oneAnimal = animals[index];
System.out.println("row # " + index + " in animas is " + oneAnimal);
```

Comment: "может не правильно я это называю, но суть та же)" - так и есть, массив строк, все верно.